# error using two cursors in plsql code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables ERROR_DESCRIPTION and ERROR_COLUMN.

> ERROR_DESCRIPTION has below data :
>   "error processing column a_type"
>   "error processing column a_type"
>   "error processing column a_type"
>
> ERROR_COLUMN has below data:
>    "abc",123334,"jdjjd"
>    "jdjd",2344,"djjd"
>    "djjd",234,"kkfkf"

at last my data should look like this :

> error processing column a_type -"abc",123334,"jdjjd"
>    error processing column a_type - "jdjd",2344,"djjd"

so on ...

"a_type" is  column name from ERROR_COLUMN  table

i am trying to achieve this using cursors .

```
declare    
cursor c_log is  select * from ERROR_DESCRIPTION where error_data_log like'error%' ORDER BY error_data_log;   
r_log ERROR_DESCRIPTION %ROWTYPE;   
v_error varchar2(1000);    
cursor c_dsc is select * from ERROR_COLUMN;
r_dsc ERROR_COLUMN%ROWTYPE;
begin 
 open c_log;    
loop    
     fetch c_log into v_error;      
     open c_dsc ;    
          fetch c_dsc into r_dsc     
          dbms_output.put_line( 'error is'||v_error||'-'||r_dsc.xyz);

 close c_dsc ;


end loop;   
close c_log;   
end ;
```

i am not able to get desired result .

`r_dsc.xyz` is column defined for that record type

can any one tell how i can i get above result.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just joining the data sets together?

Comment: there is  no common column  in both the tables.

Comment: You can join on the result of a function applied to a column.

Comment: can u provide me an example supporting your comment

Comment: FROM table_a JOIN table_b on upper(table_a.col1) = SUBSTR(table_b.col3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer you not use `cursor` when you can achieve the result with simple queries, you can get the result you mentioned with below `join` using `substr` function:

```
select d.val || substr(d.val,24) || c.val2 || c.val3
from ERROR_DESCRIPTION d
join ERROR_COLUMN c on substr(d.val,24)=c.val1
```

assuming your structure is: `ERROR_DESCRIPTION(val)`, `ERROR_COLUMN(val1,val2,val2)` according to sample data you provided.

**EDIT:**(after comments and edit of question) if you don't have a specific formula or pattern for join and you want to join them only on base of number of recor then use `rownum` within `subquery`:

```
select d.val || '-' || c.val1,c.val2,c.val3
from (select rownum rn,val from ERROR_DESCRIPTION) d
join (select rownum rn,val1,val2,val3 from ERROR_COLUMN) c
on d.rn=c.rn
```

Comment: there is no common column in both the tables so join is not possible i guess

Comment: as in desired output you are joining on base of `substr(d.val,24)=c.val1`

Comment: above code  is concatenating the  results from two cursors  . Its not joining the two table

Comment: i have formated the desired result . plz now can u check and provide me the solution